# how to force the user to sign in every time?

Tags: android, authentication, user-management

Im developing an android application for the first time (no prior experience whit coding....). Mainly the app is going to be used at work as a tool for service technicians. The app is almost ready for field testing, but there is one thing i need the app to do before that. I need the app to force the user to log in every time its opened. This is because some of the info on the app is confidential, and only people that currently works for the company is allowed to have this info. Whit firebase i can then block the users that leave the company, or users that are not verified. Currently the users sign in whit google and they stay signed in until they clear the app data or delete it.

I have looked far and wide for the answer to this, but i have only come across different use of timers.

If anyone has a better solution to this "safety" issue, im open to anything.

Comment: Do you really want to loose all your potential users?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Google Sign-In for authentication, there is no out of the box support for forcing your user to authenticate with Google every time they use your app.

This makes sense, because the user is still authed with Google on your phone. A login system only authenticates the user; it doesn't inherently protect data stored on the device. As long as Google has a valid access token, the user won't have to type a username and password again (and simply clicking "login with Google" again doesn't really provide extra protection here).

If your primary concern is blocking access to users who have left the company, you should be covered if you are using Google Apps for your company. If you disable the user's account, their access tokens should become invalid. Google Apps admins can also manually revoke access to specific apps for specific users.

If you don't use Google Apps (e.g. your users are using @gmail.com accounts or accounts from a domain outside fo your control), you might want to consider implementing a list of users allowed to access the application, and verify the current user has access by checking that list via an API call on launch.

If the goal is really protecting the confidential information in the application, you might want to take an approach similar to Android Pay in which you require your user to set and enter a PIN number to access the application. As an added benefit, you can then use that PIN to encrypt any confidential data you are storing locally.

Comment: the problem whit the access token is that the app is not checking if its still valid or not. Is there a way to make the app validate the token at least?

Comment: What are you using the access token for? If you are using it, Google API calls will fail if the token is invalid. This should be a moot point though, because you shouldn't get the `onConnected()` callback when your app starts up if the user is no longer signed in or no longer has access to the application. See [this for an example](https://developers.google.com/games/services/training/signin) of re-authing the user on subsequent launches.

Comment: thank you :) re authing the user was just what i needed

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you take a look into shared preferences and every time when the user is back into the app you send them to the login activity.